# Examples for header components in ag-grid using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

Are there any non-trivial examples of doing the new header components in ag-grid with Reactjs? I would also have to create the filtering menus as well, since ag-grid says that is now the developer's responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-react-example repo has an example that includes both header and header group components, including showing how to do filtering.

It's worth noting that although you do need to supply the GUI for filtering (as you're replacing the entire header component), you don't need to write your own filtering code - you can still use the underlying ag-Grid filters, you just need to provide hooks etc to do so on menu clicks etc.

Comment: Nothing but errors in this project.   Versions not exist, tried altering all the versions to be proper.   Had components that doesn't even exists, removed those.  After I finally got it to not fail on npm install, it crashes on startup, shutting back down.

Comment: I've just clean cloned, installed deps and started the example - it all looks ok to me. What errors are you seeing? What version(s) are missing?

Comment: npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for d3@4.9.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'ag-grid-react-example'
npm ERR! notarget

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in that repo. A direct link to a specific file would help. In addition, the standard at SO is copying relevant info to your answer.